# Does union pay and JCB card uses same specifications of EMV cards?

Tags: terminal, credit-card, pos

can we read union pay and JCB cards using the specifications described in EMV standards for contact and contact less technologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it in the lab for development purposes. For production Contactless and Contact EMV Kernels implementations must be certified.

EMV Contact terminal flow is the same for both schemes. The differences from the card profiles not visible from terminal contact interface.

In regards Contactless:

- JCB uses EMV Contactless Book C-5 Kernel 5 Specification,
- CUP uses EMV Contactless Book C-7 Kernel 7 Specification.

See EMVCo site for details.